# Reset AD password from .NET

Tags: c#, active-directory, passwords

I've been asked to create a web app for users to reset their AD password if they forgot it.

I know we can use something like that for when the user is already logged into the intranet and just wants to change the current password:

```
oPrincipalContext = new PrincipalContext(... );
UserPrincipal oUserPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(oPrincipalContext, userName);
oUserPrincipal.ChangePassword(oldPassword, newPassword);
oUserPrincipal.Save();
```

This is working fine but how can I do something similar without having the old password? Is there any call for this?

Comment: Just remember that resetting someone's password bypasses the password history restrictions. If you are taking the new password from the user and then resetting it using a privileged account, they will be able to set it to the same password every time. You may not care (or be willing to accept that) but just be aware.

Comment: The point here is to allow users to reset their password when they don't remember it. He have a way to securely send a link to them and we want them to be able to just reset the password without having to enter the old value.

Comment: I just tried using SetPassword(..) and I'm getting an Action Denie error

Comment: Are you running it with administrative credentials? (an account that has the "Reset password" permission on all your user accounts)

Comment: After giving the Reset Password permission to the user that was running this code it worked! Thanks a lot.